# java going through array field without creating new instance

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to write a method which gets an `Object` and does some logic with the `Object`'s fields.

My method looks like:

```java
public void exampleCast(Object obj) {
    Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {                    
        if (field.getClass().isArray()) {
        
        /*
            HOW CAN I GO OVER THE ARRAY FIELDS , WITHOUT CREATING NEW INSATCNE ?
            SOMETHING LIKE:
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
               array[i] ...
            }
            
        */  
        } else {
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

And an example of objects:

```java
class TBD1 {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int[] arrInt = new int[10];
    public byte[] arrByte = new byte[10];
}
```

And the call to my method:

```java
TBD1 tbd1 = new TBD1();
exampleCast(tbd1);
```

In my method, I don't know how can I get the array values without create new instance (using the `newInstance` method)
Is it possible?  (please see the comment I wrote in my example)

I have read those 2 websites:

- http://jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/two_side_notes_about_arrays
- http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/arrays.html

... but I didn't get what I wanted to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, you might use [`java.lang.reflect.Array`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) and something like

```
if (field.getType().isArray()) { // <-- should be getType(), thx @Pshemo
    Object array = field.get(obj);
    int len = Array.getLength(array);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        Object v = Array.get(array, i);
        System.out.println(v);
    }
} // ...
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `getType` instead of `getClass`? If I am not mistaken `getClass` invoked on `Field` instance will return us `Field.class` which is definitely not an array. What we want to do is check if *type* of variable is array.